Cannot display video from inside docker container:
Upon running an X application inside my container I get the following error:
* Errno 111: Connection refused
* Error location: /src/darknet/src-lib/image_opencv.cpp, create_window_cv(), line #231
* Error message:  exception caught while creating, moving, or resizing the window "Demo": OpenCV(4.5.4) ./modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:635: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

I've ran the container as:
docker run -v /home/vfbsilva/Source/darknet_meu_serpro/:/darknet -it --rm --gpus all -e DISPLAY=:0 sherensberk/darknet:2204.550.1241-devel

So I would expect it would connect to display:0 what am I missing?
Ive tried xhost command with no luck. I've ran: xhost +localhost
Im running the image as:
docker run --privileged -v /home/vfbsilva/Source/darknet_meu_serpro/:/darknet -it --env="DISPLAY" --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --rm --gpus all sherensber

When you set DISPLAY=:0 it is looking for a local socket.  This may vary, depending on your platform.  eg on my Debian 12 machine the socket is in /tmp/.X11-unix/X0.  So my first attempt would be to use -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix so see if pushing that socket into the container will let it see the socket.. that might work!
The exact path may vary, depending on your distro. You might be able to find it by running lsof against your X server process, or by netstat or ss
Failing that we can try and use TCP based communication.  Here we set DISPLAY to your hostname:0.  Now the X client will try to talk TCP to the server.  So we also need to allow remote connections using the xhost command.  xhost + will  disable all network security (so be careful; learn the xhost command to limit to minimum necessary subnets).
This may not be enough, though; the default for many distros is to disable the network listener.  Enabling that will depend on your setup.  If you do ss | grep 6000 and get no output then your X server not set up to allow network connections.  How you do this configuration would need to be another question, and should include information about your setup (eg distro, window manager, how it's started up, etc).

Ive tried xhost command with no luck. I've ran:
xhost +localhost
im running the image as:
docker run --privileged -v /home/vfbsilva/Source/darknet_meu_serpro/:/darknet -it --env="DISPLAY" --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --rm --gpus all sherensberk/darknet:2204.550.1241-devel

Display is not a constant value for all machines, just set with the current local value present on $DISPLAY. use xhost local:root insted of xhost + might be a good idea.
xhost +

docker run -it --network=host --env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro --gpus all --rm sherensberk/darknet:2204.550.1241-devel

Worked on Ubuntu24.04 and Fedora40.

This did not work for me.
xhost +local:
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
